# (xlib) put bitmap on the desktop

Tags: c++, x11

It is possible in xlib put bitmap directly on desktop (Default Root Window) ?.
I need insert my bitmap on the desktop and move it.

Only on the desktop does not create a new window and insert there.

Thanks for response,
tango

Comment: take a look at xv or xsetroot. usually you can just open the root window as a drawing surface and paint your bitmap there.

Comment: note that default screen root often is completely covered by another window, for example nautilus window handling "desktop" behaviour (icons, rubber band etc) - check if this is the case in your system with `xwininfo -root -tree`